# Can I deploy my azure function on a normal VM?

Tags: c#, azure, serverless-framework

A client would like to go to the cloud in the future, but I would like to start working on new devs using Azure Functions (locally using the func.exe). Is there a way that I can deploy my azure functions code to a normal VM running normal IIS (not Azure itself) and have it working on Prod? This will make it easy to go to Azure when the client gives his go ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Azure Functions Runtime](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/introducing-azure-functions-runtime-preview/) could be a solution for your issue.

You can also use a Visual Studio Subscription, which depending on the subscription, include some azure volume. This volume can be used for testing purpose and moving to another tennant on azure is not hard.

Comment: Now Azure Functions Runtime Installer is not available. What is the alternative?